# Intersection of two arithmetic progressions

Tags: arithmetic-progression

Using elementary matrix row and column operations on the system of two diophantine equations, namely, $N=an+b$ and $N=cn+d$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}^0$, it can be shown that the intersection of these two arithmetic progressions is another arithmetic progression $N=(ac)n+c\delta+d$ where $\delta\in\mathbb{N}:a|\left(c\delta+d-b\right)$.

For example the intersection of $N=5n+3$ and $N=7n-2$ by the above formula is $N=35n+33$

Is there a way to transform $\delta$ such that the condition of divisibility is eliminated?

Comment: Do I understand you right that your question is about the intersection
$(b+a\mathbb{Z}) \cap (d+c\mathbb{Z})$? -- This intersection is nonempty
if and only if $b \equiv d$ mod ${\rm gcd}(a,c)$.


Comment: And when it is nonempty, the intersection is a single arithmetic progression modulo $ac/\gcd(a,c)$. What you have written is equivalent, I think, but much more complicated.

Comment: Yes the question was for the intersection of `$\left(b+a\mathbb{Z},d+c\mathbb{Z}\right)$` and `$gcd(a,c)=1$` so that it is always nonempty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a divisibility criterion, the intersection of two such arithmetic progressions can be found using the chinese remainder theorem.

In your example notice that any such $N$ in the intersection satisfies:

$N \equiv 3 \bmod 5$

and

$N \equiv 5 \bmod 7$

Solving gives $N \equiv 33 \bmod 35$.

Comment: You can avoid a divisibity criterion and use the chinese remainder theorem only when the moduli are relatively prime.  A better example would have used 10 and 14 instead of 5 and 7.

Comment: The question is for coprime moduli. It appears that this is it: Chinese remainder theorem with some basic algebra and modular arithmetic.

Comment: Well yeah but under conditions described above (on gcd$(a,b)$) you can still do a similar thing just it isn't as straight-forward.